# PHP Connect over ssh with public key and switch user to execute commands

Tags: php, ssh, switch-statement

Good evening,

currently I'm developing on a script that uses PHP. PHP uses "ssh2_connect" with Public Key as command for the connection to a remote host. Furthermore i use ssh2_exec to execute some commands with user_a. I would like to switch to user_b to execute antoher command and 
optional to return to user_a.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('192.168.2.100', 22, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));

if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, 'user_a', './ssh/id_rsa.pub', './ssh/id_rsa'))
{
  echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n<br />";
}
else
{
  die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}



if(!($stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "sudo su user_b ; cd ~ ; ls -la" )) )
{
    echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
}
else
{

    stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );

    echo stream_get_contents($stream);

}



ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit');
unset($connection);
```

The problem is a normal command works well but switching a user returns in a timeout (sudo File was edited)... I've already tried it with fwrite to send commands.
;
Is there any solution to fix this with a few commands (own php code) or is it better to use http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: sudo's going to prompt for a password. Since you're not sending one, the connection will wait for one until things time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could probably do this:

```
echo password | sudo su user_b ; cd ~ ; ls -la
```

The downside of this would be that it'd show up in your bash history.

Here's a way to do it with phpseclib without having it show up in your bash history without having it show up in your bash history:

Here's a way to get the password to sudo with [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/intro.html) / interactive mode:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('./ssh/id_rsa');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.2.100');
if ($ssh->login('user_r', $rsa)) {
    echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n<br />";
} else {
    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}

echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("sudo su user_b\n");
$output = $ssh->read('#[pP]assword[^:]*:|username@username:~\$#', NET_SSH2_READ_REGEX);
echo $output;
if (preg_match('#[pP]assword[^:]*:#', $output)) {
    $ssh->write("password\n");
    echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
}

$ssh->write("cd ~\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');

$ssh->write("ls -la\n");
echo $ssh->read('username@username:~$');
?>
```

Here's how to do it with phpseclib if you don't care about bash history:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey('./ssh/id_rsa');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('192.168.2.100');
if ($ssh->login('user_r', $rsa)) {
    echo "Public Key Authentication Successful\n<br />";
} else {
    die('Public Key Authentication Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec("sudo su user_b ; cd ~ ; ls -la");
```